# operate on row-compressed format from igraph_sparsemat_t

Tags: c, igraph

Is it possible to build an `igraph_sparsemat_t` from an already available matrix stored in row-compressed (CSR) format and not set every value with `igraph_sparsemat_entry()`?

Also can I extract the CSR structure from an `igraph_sparsemat_t` so that I can use the CSR-matrix with other libraries?

I know that conversion from `igraph_sparsemat_t` to `igraph` is possible, but I don't know what I could do from there on.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to do ? Copy it, add new members or ? If not time and memory is a problem, then convert to normal matrix and use all the igraph_matrix_ functions.

Comment: @split That pretty much defeats the purpose of ever using any sparse matrix data structure. What OP is asking is not even to have to convert the CSC representation into a list of `(i,j) -> value` index/value pairs (which would be the simple way to convert this to another sparse library's format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The igraph documentation mentions that `igraph_sparsemat_t` is a thin wrapper for [the CXSparse library](http://faculty.cse.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html)'s datatype. The documentation for that library is essentially this book:

- [Timothy A. Davis: Direct Methods for Sparse Linear Systems](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/book/10.1137/1.9780898718881?mobileUi=0&)

But you don't really need the book to solve this. You can dig a bit in the source and find `igraph_sparsemat_t` just contains a `cs_di_sparse`, which is

```
typedef struct cs_di_sparse  /* matrix in compressed-column or triplet form */
{
    int nzmax ;     /* maximum number of entries */
    int m ;         /* number of rows */
    int n ;         /* number of columns */
    int *p ;        /* column pointers (size n+1) or col indices (size nzmax) */
    int *i ;        /* row indices, size nzmax */
    double *x ;     /* numerical values, size nzmax */
    int nz ;        /* # of entries in triplet matrix, -1 for compressed-col */
} cs_di ;
```

You can build or read this directly.

The igraph documentation mentions that this may contain *either* a CSC representation of a triplet matrix. Pay attention to this (see comment on the last entry).

Do look at the memory allocation/deallocation functions in `cs.h` (`cs_di_malloc`/`cs_di_free`/etc.) and use them instead of you standard malloc/free, to ensure that a compatible `free` is used on memory allocated with a certain `malloc`.

Note that the MATLAB interface of CSparse (take a look at the sources I linked above) also uses this approach: it manipulates the struct directly.

Finally, do pay attention that igraph interprets this matrix as CSC, not CSR. If you convert to another library's data structure, you might need to transpose. If you do that, you would need to convert to (index, value) pairs anyway.

Comment: Great help! Also thanks for pointing out the `cs_di_malloc`. I wrote 'column-compressed' and abreviated with 'CSR', guess it was a little late yesterday..

Comment: I recognized cs uses 32 bit integers, but I need 64 indices for very large matrices.

Comment: @ps3lister This is something you should [take up with the igraph developers](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues). I do notice that in the latest version of CSparse the index type is adaptable, so it should be possible to do the same for CXSparse, and eventually for the igraph version of the same. However, since in igraph the main purpose of this type is to store adjacency matrices, this would make sense if igraph graphs can also store more than 2^31-1 nodes. I do not know if this is the case.

Comment: @ps3lister Out of curiosity, what other library are you adapting this to?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm also using Intel MKL and metis for partitioning.